# Matching a specific line that starts with double forward slash using sed

Tags: sed

I currently have a sed command that matches a specific phrase in a file, and replaces all lines of that file with the full text of a different file. This works for the phrase "### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###"

```
sed -n -e '1,/^### REPLACE EVERYTHING AFTER THIS LINE ###$/{ p; d; }' \
       -e 'r replacement_file.txt' \
       -e 'q' original_file.txt > original_file.txt.new &&
mv original_file.txt.new original_file.txt
```

This command works for text files, but in needing to replace files with javascript style comments, I've hit a bit of a snag. The new line/phrase I'm trying to match is now the following (and note I want to match **this** specific comment, not all comments that start with the double forward slash):

```
//REPLACE AFTER THIS
```

I've hit a snag as I'm currently failing to escape the double forward slash. I've tried escaping the two characters with a backslash, but that did not work. My current (non-working) command is the following:

```
sed -n -e ‘1,/^\/\/REPLACE AFTER THIS$/{ p; d; }’\ 
       -e 'r replacement_file.txt' \
       -e 'q' original_file.txt > original_file.txt.new && mv original_file.txt.new original_file.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use other delimiters than slashes by preceding the startimg one with a backslash: `sed -n '\|^//|p'`

Comment: Once you fix the quotes, `\/\/` should work - if it doesn't, try making the match less specific e.g. removing the `$` anchor in case there is trailing whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to those who commented, in addition to fixing the non-ASCII quote, here is the working command:

```
sed -n -e '1,\|^//REPLACE TEST$|{ p; d; }' \
    -e 'r replacement_file.txt' \
    -e 'q' original_file.txt > original_file.txt.new && mv original_file.txt.new original_file.txt
```